# error magento 1.9 - Use of undefined constant tmp - assumed 'tmp'

Tags: magento, caching, error-handling, magento-1.9

I get this error whenever I try to login to the adminpanel
tried adding tmp folder in root nothing helps
[image]

Comment: Delete var/cache folder

Comment: deleted cache and session folder content but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

It looks like somebody modified `lib/Zend/Cache.php` to redefine the tmp directory (a common workaround if the system temp directory determined by Zend is not writable), but violated PHP syntax like this

```
'cache_dir' => tmp
```

instead of

```
'cache_dir' => 'tmp'
```

Replace `tmp` without quotes with `'tmp'` with quotes and it should work.

By the way, if you turn off `MAGE_DEVELOPER_MODE` (usually set in `.htaccess` or `index.php`), Notices like this won't break your site and just be logged. You should do this on a production site, but leave the developer mode active on your dev system to better find those hidden errors.

Comment: That's a totally unrelated error message, sounds like you removed `MAGE_RUN_CODE` instead of `MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE`.

Comment: No I only turned off MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE

Comment: Then it did work but you have more than one issues. What did you change?

Comment: The notice disappeared, like I told you. But obviously you have more bugs.